# INSERT new rows, UPDATE old rows: how?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I am making a PHP utility that imports and analyzes a CSV file into `$data`, and whether or not to INSERT "new" rows into the database (`$saveNew`).

Right now, I have a bit of an ugly mess: (in generalized pseudo-PHP)

```
function synchronize($data,$saveNew) {
    $existing_ids = $table->find_all('ID'); //array of ID's in the table
    $incoming_ids = get_key('ID',$data); //grabs the ID field from each record
    $new_ids = array_diff($incoming_ids,$existing_ids);

    foreach ($data as $record) {
        if (in_array($record['ID'],$new_ids)) { //it's new
            if ($saveNew) $table->insert($record);
            else continue;
        } else {
            $table->update($record);
        }
     }
 }
```

To me, this just has a smell, and I think I could accomplish this in just a single query, except that I'm not that familiar with SQL.

I'm using a simple ORM in my app, but I can easily just use straight SQL.

Oh, and I'm using MySQL.

Can this be done with just one query? It seems like this would be a common problem with a simple solution, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at MySQL's `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY ...` syntax, which allows you to do just that: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Whether you want to implement that in your ORM or in that specific subroutine of yours is up to you...

Comment: This looks much better, but wouldn't this only apply if `$saveNew` is true? If we want to `synchronize($data,false)`, then we don't want to `INSERT` at all. Is there such a thing as `UPDATE IF EXISTS`?

Comment: There's no need for an `UPDATE IF EXISTS`...  when you call `UPDATE ... WHERE id = 5`, if id `5` doesn't exist, it just won't update anything...  No error, just no updates...

Comment: @ircmaxwell: Oh wow, talk about a "duh!" moment for me. I'm apparently not thinking very straight... :D

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique row identifier, you can use the [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO foo (id, col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?, ?) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = VALUES(col1), col2 = VALUES(col2);
```

Then, when you bind `NULL, 4, 5` it'll insert a new row (assuming `id` is an autoincrement column)

When you bind `1, 4, 5` it'll insert a new row if there is no row 1, otherwise it'll update row 1's `col1` and `col2` fields to `4` and `5` respectively...